# Buffon's needle.

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a 
foor made of parallel strips of wood, each the same width,
and we drop a needle onto the 
floor. What is the probability that the needle will
lie across a line between two strips?
This is known as the Buffon's needle problem. How can I write a
program that will estimate pi  using the Bufon method?(In Python)

Comment: Not the Buffon method but similar: draw random points in a square and count the fraction of those that fall in the inscribed circle.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the width of the strips is $1$ and the length of the needle is $2k$.

1. Take a random number $x$ between $0$ and $1$. This will be the distance between the centre of the needle and the line at its left.
2. Take a random number $\alpha$ beteewn $0$ and $\pi/2$. This will be the angle (in radians) between the strips and the needle (if the angle is $0$, the needle is parallel to the strips; the probability of this happens is $0$, although).
3. If $k\cos\alpha>x$, then the needle intersects the line at its left. If $k\cos\alpha>1-x$, then the needle intersects the line at its right.

Can you make your program with these tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't performing the needle drop experiment physicially, then you need to know $\pi$ in order to do the simulated sampling for drops of the needle (see the other answer by ajotatxe). So you need to already know $\pi$ in order to estimate $\pi$ this way using a computer. That basically defeats the purpose, does it not?

Comment: Well, you could pick two points $x_1,x_2$ at random and then let $x_2' = x_1+r {x_2-x_1 \over \|x_2-x_1\|}$.

Comment: @copper.hat: are you sure that the distribution of angles will be uniform ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Good question. Probably not... (At least not without involving $\pi$.)

Comment: @cooper.hat: instead you can generate random vectors and keep those that fall in an annulus inscribed in the square; normalize them to the needle length.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Good idea.

Comment: @copper.hat: $\tan(\arctan\frac{x_2}{x_1})=\frac{x_2}{x_1}$ is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Oops, dunno what I was thinking.

Comment: How about selecting $\theta$ randomly in $[0,7]$ and reject those that satisfy $\theta >6$ and $\sin \theta >0$? The accepted points will be uniformly distributed on $[0, 2 \pi]$ (avoids explicit use of $\pi$).

Comment: @copper.hat: why not, provided you can compute the sine without using the value of $\pi$ at all.